# Iteration limit reached - simple counter in VHDL FSM

Tags: iteration, vhdl, limit, counter, fsm

I'm having "Iteration limit reached" error in a simple FSM.
This is a part of of a bigger FSM I have to do for a class assignment, and I tracked the problem to this specific part.
The FSM will be controlling a counter, the state IDLE waits for inputs, ZERO sets the counter to zero, and the INCREMENT state increments the counter by one.

When simulating, the error occurs at the first time the input "inc" is high and the clock rises.
If I change the statement "temp := temp + 1;" for "temp := anything" the error stops. I really don't know what can be wrong, as for what I have found this error occurs when changing signals in the process sensitivity list inside the process itself.

I'm using Quartus II for the simulation.

Sorry for english mistakes.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity fsm is
    port
    (
        clock:      in std_logic;
        reset:      in std_logic;

        inc:            in std_logic;

        count:      out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
        cur_state:  out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0)
    );
end fsm;

architecture behaviour of fsm is
    type state_type is (IDLE, INCREMENT, ZERO);
    signal PS, NS: state_type;  

begin       
    sync_proc: process (clock, reset)
    begin   
        if (reset = '1') then
            PS <= ZERO;
        elsif (rising_edge(clock)) then
            PS <= NS;           
        end if;
    end process sync_proc;

    comb_proc: process (PS, inc)
        variable temp: unsigned (13 downto 0);
    begin
        case PS is
            when IDLE =>
                if (inc = '1') then
                    NS <= INCREMENT;
                else
                    NS <= IDLE;
                end if;             
            when INCREMENT =>
                temp := temp + 1;
                NS <= IDLE;
            when ZERO =>
                temp := "00000000000000";
                NS <= IDLE;
            when others =>
                NS <= IDLE;
        end case;

        count <= std_logic_vector(temp);
    end process comb_proc;

    with PS select
        cur_state <=    "00" when IDLE,
                             "01" when INCREMENT,
                             "10" when ZERO,
                             "11" when others;  
end behaviour;
```

Comment: Your code simulates successfully with an added testbench [fsm_tb.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uPgib.png). Note that reset causes PS = ZERO which initializes temp. Please show your actual error message and show your simulation. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Also note the use clause `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;` is not needed.

Comment: A post synthesis simulation might encounter a combinatorial loop with temp based on the lack of a sequential circuit inference (There's no clock edge used to increment temp). If `PS` is a one hot state there is no possibility of combinatorial glitches for the use `INCREMENT` as a latch enable.  But all the time `INCREMENT` is true, the temp latch will be updated and it provides a feedback loop which can encounter the iteration limit. This is consistent with the behavior you've described, but not applicable to the behavioral code you provide.

Comment: `I'm having "Iteration limit reached" error in a simple FSM.` Then it's probably the error-prone 2-process style. Look at single-process state machines.

Comment: After some hours trying to figure what was wrong, I switched to a  single-process FSM and had no trouble with it. I am new in VHDL, and every material I had read suggested 2-process FSM. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very serious CONCEPTUAL mistake in your case statement. Because it produces a combinational circuit (the combinational part of your FSM), it does not have memory, so it can't implement the equation "temp := temp + 1" (because, having no memory, it doesn't know what the value of temp is).

You can see more about this in chapter 11 of "Finite State Machines in Hardware...", by V.Pedroni, published by MIT.